# Normal boot (systemd) not working

Tags: upstart, systemd

I've accidentally changed the UUID of /home partition. I corrected the UUID by updating /etc/fstab. Now ubuntu in normal boot is stuck at boot logo but I can boot up using upstart. How do I fix this?

Comment: As evidenced by the fact that you've already lead one answerer on a wild goose chase, "it is not working" is a utterly useless description of what your computer is doing.  Describe what your computer is doing, precisely and in detail by [edit]ing your question, and answerers will have a sporting chance of helping you.

Comment: It is stuck at boot logo! Chill man!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root file system UUID would also have been written into the GRUB configuration file, /boot/grub/grub.conf, and that should be corrected as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help but this file has UUID of my root directory. But I've mounted /home in different partition. So  no need to correct root file system UUID.  Can you suggest me any other solution?

Comment: Yes, right. Sorry. Maybe it helps to re-run grub-install and update-grub?

Comment: it worked! I reinstalled grub and it booted perfectly fine!